# How to prevent iMessage syncing without access to device

Tags: mac, icloud, messages

I foolishly logged into someone's iPad with my Apple ID. This person is now receiving my full communications on iMessage. I know I can remove my account from that iPad but I don't have access to it. How can I stop the device from getting my iMessages without physical access?

Answer (score 4):

Try changing your Apple ID password. That'll lock any device out of any service using your Apple ID without the new password. Good luck to you!

You can change it from your iOS Device, right in the iTunes or App Store at the bottom go to "Apple ID: [Your Apple ID here]", click on "View Apple ID" and change your password.

Answer (score -1):

You can manage devices that have access to your Apple ID through iTunes/iTunes Store.

1. Open iTunes
2. Click "Store" on the menu bar (Mac OS X).
3. Select "View my Apple ID (xxx@xxx.xxx)" from the drop down menu.
4. Log-in to the Apple ID you wish to revoke access to.
5. Under the "iTunes In the Cloud" section you can manage/add devices.

   - *I'm honestly not sure if this revokes access to iMessages, but I assume it does.*

Comment: This only manages device connections to iTunes iCloud content, not iMessages!